# Show that a certain norm (here $L^1$) satisfies norm properties

Tags: functional-analysis

I hope the question title is not confusing, since my problem is actually not directly related to norms (suggestions welcome). But here we go:

In some lecture example it is shown that for $f \in C([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$,
$$\lVert f \rVert_1 = \int_{-1}^1 |f(x)| dx$$
is a norm on $C([-1,1], \mathbb{R})$.

For showing positivity the author simply states "$\lVert f \rVert_1 > 0$ for $f \neq 0$ by continuity of $f$". Could someone explain that to me? I'm not able to relate continuity to the claim. Is it somehow related to the fact that the absolute value function is continuous and the composition of continuous functions is again continuous? What then? I am unable to find an exact explanation, yet I think it's just a tiny misconception. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is cont., so is $|f|$. If $f \neq 0$, there exists some point $a$ where $|f(a)| \neq 0$. By continuity, there exits an interval, where $|f| \neq 0$ and hence positive. So, the overall integral is positive.

Comment: Omg that was easy... Thank you so much!

Comment: @andreee Welcome to stack exchange.  If this answer solved your problem, which it seemed to ,  hit the check mark next to it to accept it.  You can also hit the up arrow to give more positive feedback to any number of helpful answers in addition to the one you vote for

Comment: @Alan: Thank you, I'm aware of that, but: "You can accept an answer in 3 minutes" + I need 15 reputation to vote up ;-)

Comment: @andreee Well, I'll get you that little bit closer then.   Welcome again!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f\neq 0$, then by continuity of $f$ we could have a small interval $I\subset (-1,1)$ such that $f>\alpha>0$ in $I$ for some $\alpha>0$, Then I believe you could take it from here.